# if the subsequences $f_{2n-1}$, $\langle f_{2n}\rangle$ of $\langle f_{n}\rangle$ both converge to l, then $\langle f_{n}\rangle$ also converges to l

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Approach:

\begin{align*}
\mid f_{2n-1} - l \mid \le \epsilon \forall n \ge m1 \\
\mid f_{2n} - l \mid \le \epsilon \forall n \ge m2  \\
\end{align*}

$m=\max(m_{1},m_{2}) \Rightarrow\\$
\begin{align*}
\mid f_{2n-1} - l \mid \le \epsilon \forall n \ge m\\
\mid f_{2n} - l \mid \le \epsilon \forall n \ge m 
\end{align*}

From the last step, how can we conclude that:=
\begin{align*}
\mid f_{n} - l \mid \le \epsilon \forall n \ge m 
\end{align*}

Comment: It may be quite automatical, by case working on the parity of $n$.

Comment: Assume if possible there is a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ that doesn't converge to $l$. However, every term of $u_{n_k}$ is either a term of $f_{2n}$ or $f_{2n-1}$, so $u_{n_k}$ also converges to $l$, a contradiction.